# if modular inverse is injective or not

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Prove that the function $f(x)=(8x+5) \bmod 17$ is injective on the set $
\{0,1,2,3,\cdots,15,16\}$. If so, give its inverse function

I know how to find the inverse of modular function and that will be $\frac{x-5}8 \bmod 17$.
I need help in understanding this question.

Comment: @Kemono Chen thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hint: In arithmetic modulo $n$, if $\gcd(m, n) = 1$, multiplication by $m$ is injective. (In your case, $\gcd(8, 17) = 1$, so multiplication by $8$ is injective.)

And here is the kicker: There is a number $m'$ such that division by $m$ is the same as multiplication by $m'$. Find that number, and you're basically done.

Comment: Hey! If I am not wrong then injective means that every value of x will point to unique element in set but here if x = 4 and x = 21 then both will map to 3 so it not injective?

Comment: is the number 15?

Comment: @user10792303 $4,21$ are the same in mod $17.$ So your comment doesn't contradict injective.

Answer (score 0):

The question asks you to prove that the function $f$ is injective, that is

> if $a,b\in\{0,1,2,\dots,16\}$ and $f(a)=f(b)$, then $a=b$.

When a function from a set to itself is injective, it is also surjective (pigeonhole principle). Thus the function $f$ has an inverse.

Hint for finding the inverse: $2\cdot8=16$.

Comment: Does this mean that value of x can only be from set?

Comment: @user10792303 Yes, that's what the problem says.

Comment: oh I thought x could be any number